# Abstract Enum Class using ABCMeta and EnumMeta

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

## Simple Example

The goal is to create an abstract enum class through a metaclass deriving from both `abc.ABCMeta` and `enum.EnumMeta`. For example:

```
import abc
import enum

class ABCEnumMeta(abc.ABCMeta, enum.EnumMeta):
    pass

class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self):
        pass

class B(A, enum.IntEnum, metaclass=ABCEnumMeta):
    X = 1

class C(A):
    pass
```

Now, on Python3.7, this code will be interpreted without error (on 3.6.x and presumably below, it will not). In fact, everything looks great, our MRO shows `B` derived from both  `A` and `IntEnum`.

```
>>> B.__mro__
(<enum 'B'>, __main__.A, abc.ABC, <enum 'IntEnum'>, int, <enum 'Enum'>, object)
```

## Abstract Enum is not Abstract

However, even though `B.foo` has not been defined, we can still instantiate `B` without any issue, and call `foo()`.

```
>>> B.X
<B.X: 1>
>>> B(1)
<B.X: 1>
>>> B(1).foo()
```

This seems rather weird, since any other class that derives from ABCMeta cannot be instantiated, even if I use a custom metaclass.

```
>>> class NewMeta(type): 
...     pass
... 
... class AbcNewMeta(abc.ABCMeta, NewMeta):
...     pass
... 
... class D(metaclass=NewMeta):
...     pass
... 
... class E(A, D, metaclass=AbcNewMeta):
...     pass
...
>>> E()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class E with abstract methods foo
```

## Question

Why does a class using a metaclass derived from `EnumMeta` and `ABCMeta` effectively ignore `ABCMeta`, while any other class using a metaclass derived from `ABCMeta` use it? This is true even if I custom define the `__new__` operator.

```
class ABCEnumMeta(abc.ABCMeta, enum.EnumMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        # Commented out lines reflect other variants that don't work
        #return abc.ABCMeta.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        #return enum.EnumMeta.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

I'm rather confused, since this seems to fly in the face of what a metaclass is: the metaclass should define how the class is defined and behaves, and in this case, defining a class using a metaclass that is both abstract and an enumeration creates a class that silently ignores the abstract component. Is this a bug, is this intended, or is there something greater I am not understanding?

Comment: `B(1)` does not create an instance of `B`.

Comment: @chepner Mark that as answer, since digging deeper through your comments I was able to find this:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Lib/enum.py#L525

Write it up as an answer and I'll mark it as answered. Thank you. Didn't realize that all class construction was done by the metaclass, which makes obvious sense in retrospect.

Comment: I'm not *quite* confident enough to do that; I've been digging through `enum.py` to see exactly what `EnumMeta` does.

Comment: You shall not create AbstractEnum normally, because Enum members are created at the moment of Enum class creation (and then they cannot be added later on). It make sense though to do so if you use [aenum package](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/) which provides tool (```extend_enum``` function) to create enum members dynamically. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to achieve this goal :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated on @chepner's answer, what is going on is that `Enum` metaclass overrides the normal metaclass' `__call__` method, so that an `Enum` class is never instantiated through the normal methods, and thus, `ABCMeta` checking does not trigger its abstractmethod check.

However, on class creation, the Metaclass's `__new__` is run normally, and the attributes used by the abstract-class mechanisms to mark the class as abstract do create the attribute `___abstractmethods__` on the created class.

So, all you have to do for what you intend to work, is to further customize your metaclass to perform the abstract check in the code to `__call__`:

```
import abc
import enum

class ABCEnumMeta(abc.ABCMeta, enum.EnumMeta):

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if getattr(cls, "__abstractmethods__", None):
            raise TypeError(f"Can't instantiate abstract class {cls.__name__} "
                            f"with frozen methods {set(cls.__abstractmethods__)}")
        return super().__call__(*args, **kw)
```

This will make the `B(1)` expression to fail with the same error as `abstractclass` instantiation.

Note, however, that an `Enum` class can't be further inherited anyway, and it simply creating it without the missing abstractmethods may already violate what you want to check. That is: in your example above, `class B` can be declared and `B.x` will work, even with the missing `foo` method. If you want to prevent that, just put the same check in the metaclass' `__new__`:

```
import abc
import enum

class ABCEnumMeta(abc.ABCMeta, enum.EnumMeta):

    def __new__(mcls, *args, **kw):
        cls = super().__new__(mcls, *args, **kw)
        if issubclass(cls, enum.Enum) and getattr(cls, "__abstractmethods__", None):
            raise TypeError("...")
        return cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if getattr(cls, "__abstractmethods__", None):
            raise TypeError(f"Can't instantiate abstract class {cls.__name__} "
                            f"with frozen methods {set(cls.__abstractmethods__)}")
        return super().__call__(*args, **kw)
```

(Unfortunatelly, the `ABC` abstract method check in CPython seems to be performed in native code, outside the `ABCMeta.__call__` method - otherwise, instead of mimicking the error, we could just call `ABCMeta.__call__` explicitly overriding `super`'s behavior instead of hardcoding the `TypeError` there.)

Comment: This doesn't work (at least on 3.6).

Answer (score 3):

Calling an enumerated type doesn't create a new instance. Members of the enumerated type are created immediately at class-creation time by the meta class. The `__new__` method simply performs lookup, which means `ABCMeta` is never invoked to prevent instantiation.

`B(1).foo()` works because, once you have an instance, it doesn't matter if the method was marked as abstract. It's still a real method, and can be called as such.