# Multiple inheritance metaclass conflict involving Enum

Tags: python, inheritance, enums, metaclass

I need a double inheritance for a class that is an Enum but also support my own methods.
Here's the context:

```py
import abc
from enum import Enum

class MyFirstClass(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def func(self):
        pass

class MySecondClass(Enum, MyFirstClass):
    VALUE_1 = 0
    VALUE_2 = 1
    
    def func(self):
        return 42
```

The declaration of `MySecondClass` yields the following error:

```markdown
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I tried applying [this stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720217) by doing:

```py
class MyMetaClass(type(Enum), type(MyFirstClass)):
    pass

class MyFinalClass(Enum, MyFirstClass, metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    VALUE_1 = 0
    VALUE_2 = 1
    
    def func(self):
        return 42
```

But I get the following error:

```markdown
TypeError: new enumerations should be created as `EnumName([mixin_type, ...] [data_type,] enum_type)`
```

Is this an issue specific to the `Enum` type, or am I missing something else regarding metaclasses?

Comment: In general, metaclasses don't compose. I would rethink whether you really need `FirstClass` to be an abstract base class.

Comment: For a proper abstract Enum type, use the `ABCEnumMeta` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135108/208880).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to your immediate problem is:

```
class MyFinalClass(MyFirstClass, Enum, metaclass=MyMetaClass):
    pass
```

Note that `Enum` is the last regular class listed.

For a fully functioning abstract Enum you'll want to use the `ABCEnumMeta` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135108/208880) -- otherwise missing abstract methods will not be properly flagged.